# buttons repeat issue in Dynamic adding using Visual Format Language

Tags: ios, autolayout, cocoapods

I am using the below function to add buttons same like Fred and No in the next line but no getting same button size and text at same place.

```
- (IBAction)addAnotherBranchField:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"Add Another Branch");
    UIView *superview = self;
    _buttons = [NSMutableArray array];
    self.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

    _verticalButtonConstraints = [NSMutableArray array];

    NSString* previousAnswer = [_datasource valueForField:_field.guid branchIndex:0];
    id buttonForLoadedAnswer = nil;

    for (FormListOption* option in _field.options) {

        UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;

        //Add a little padding around the text - Using edge insets does not play well with the autolayout so do it with a space instead
        [button setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat:@" %@ ",option.text] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
        [_buttons addObject:button];
        [superview addSubview: button];

    if ([option.text isEqualToString:previousAnswer]) {
        buttonForLoadedAnswer = button;
     }
    }

    paddingCounter = paddingCounter + 100;
    UIButton *addButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, paddingCounter, 32, 32)];
   [addButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"nav_newanswers.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [addButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addAnotherBranchField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [superview addSubview:addButton];
   [superview bringSubviewToFront:addButton];


   //Add the constraints
NSMutableDictionary* views = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
NSMutableString* visualLayout = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"H:|-(5)-"];
for (NSInteger i=0; i < [_buttons count]; i++) {
    NSString* name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button_%d", i];
    [views setValue:[_buttons objectAtIndex:i] forKey:name];
    [visualLayout appendFormat:@"[%@(>=80)]-", name];
}

[visualLayout appendString:@"(>=10)-|"];
[superview addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:visualLayout
                                                                  options:NSLayoutFormatAlignAllBottom
                                                                  metrics:nil
                                                                    views:views]];
}

- (void)updateVerticalConstrainsAgain:(UIView*)expandedView padding:(float)padding 
{

[self removeConstraints:_verticalButtonConstraints];
[_verticalButtonConstraints removeAllObjects];

NSString* visualFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"V:|[button]-(5)-%@|", expandedView ? [NSString stringWithFormat:@"[expanded]-(20)-"] : @""];

if (padding != 0 && expandedView == nil)
{
    visualFormat = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"V:|[button(button)]-(%f)-|",padding];
}

for (UIView* button in _buttons) {

    NSMutableDictionary* views = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:button forKey:@"button"];
    if (expandedView) {
        [views setObject:button forKey:@"expanded"];
    }

    NSArray* constraints = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:visualFormat
                                                                   options:0
                                                                   metrics:nil
                                                                     views:views];
    [self addConstraints:constraints];
    [_verticalButtonConstraints addObjectsFromArray:constraints];
}
}
```

Please explain me whaere i am getting wrong. spend my full day to get out from problems.

Comment: could you show what your `visualLayout` strings look like? and what do you get? a crash or a visually incorrect result?

Comment: You have not stated either the exact problem you are having or the expected outcome. If the issue is that you have repeated buttons and if you are calling the `addAnotherBranchField:` method multiple times, then where is your code to remove the previously added buttons (using `removeFromSuperView`)?

Comment: @Robotic Cat: thanks for review my question. you are right buddy but no need to remove previous buttons. i need to show all the buttons once again below the previously buttons.

Comment: @sergio: getting incorrect result.

Comment: what about providing the resulting `visualLayout` so we have more chance to spot what is not working?

Comment: @sergio: ok i will try to upload image here.

Comment: @SAD: do not forget the `visualLayout` string value, please...